# Connect Android Device over Proxy Server via SSH and VNC

Tags: android, ssh, vnc

I try to use SSH on Android the first time, i had read a lot about it but i cant find much, only from Android to Computer. Maybe someone can help me here:)

I have coded an APK for my own Android Device wheres create an SSH Connection over my PHP Script using Proxy Server.

I use an Debian VPS as Proxy Server. With this IP, the Android creates an Proxy.

Now i use this Comment:

```
ssh -N -L 34836:127.0.0.1:34836 newgenerateduser@23.106.XXX.XX
```

Port is generated also random every time i create an new proxy over PHP Script.

I use now an Virtual Machine with Ubuntu and enter the Comment in my Terminal with the Passwort after asking.

I start my VNC Client and want get remote Control over my Android device using VNC or SSH with this IP and Port:

```
127.0.0.1:34836
```

I got this Message:

```
lxs@linux-virtual-machine:~$ ssh -N -L 34836:127.0.0.1:34836 newgenerateduser@23.106.XXX.XX
newgenerateduser@23.106.XXX.XX's password: 
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

I also tried using `localhost` instead of IP.
There are special requirements for the Proxy Server? Or just Port blocking on it?

Thanks for your help!